# JNLP file blocked by security manager stating the error -> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied

Tags: java, jnlp, adoptopenjdk, openwebstart

I am trying to run my jnlp file which is basically getting my jenkins agent online after i reboot my pc , previously with java web start recently with OpenWebStart i am getting this issue every time when i launch jnlp file after 02 - 03 seconds it terminated the session and in log file i have seen this error

Following are the configuration
OS: Windows 10
OpenWebStart version : 1.4.0
JVM : 11.0.10
Open JDK : 1.8.0_302

I already tried to with different higher version of openjdk to check this issue and i got that error even with the OpenJDK: 1.11.---

Log File :-

```
Nov. 23, 2021 1:29:45 NACHM. org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFORMATION: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping]
Nov. 23, 2021 1:29:52 NACHM. org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.BIONetworkLayer$Reader run
INFORMATION: Waiting for ProtocolStack to start.
Nov. 23, 2021 1:29:56 NACHM. hudson.remoting.UserRequest perform
WARNUNG: LinkageError while performing UserRequest:hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$SlaveInitializer@7f43a890
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$SlaveInitializer.call(SlaveComputer.java:1050)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$SlaveInitializer.call(SlaveComputer.java:1041)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:376)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:122)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "hudson.util.RingBufferLogHandler.defaultSize" "read")
    at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:897)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:322)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPSecurityManager.checkPermission(JNLPSecurityManager.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1066)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:816)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.getInteger(Integer.java:1340)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.getInteger(Integer.java:1296)
    at hudson.util.RingBufferLogHandler.<clinit>(RingBufferLogHandler.java:39)
    ... 11 more

Nov. 23, 2021 1:30:07 NACHM. org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFORMATION: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping]
Nov. 23, 2021 1:30:11 NACHM. org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.BIONetworkLayer$Reader run
INFORMATION: Waiting for ProtocolStack to start.
Nov. 23, 2021 1:30:16 NACHM. hudson.remoting.UserRequest perform
WARNUNG: LinkageError while performing UserRequest:hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$SlaveInitializer@7ad18fca
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$SlaveInitializer.call(SlaveComputer.java:1050)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$SlaveInitializer.call(SlaveComputer.java:1041)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:376)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:122)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "hudson.util.RingBufferLogHandler.defaultSize" "read")
    at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:897)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:322)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPSecurityManager.checkPermission(JNLPSecurityManager.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1066)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:816)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.getInteger(Integer.java:1340)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.getInteger(Integer.java:1296)
    at hudson.util.RingBufferLogHandler.<clinit>(RingBufferLogHandler.java:39)
    ... 11 more
```

My JNLP file :-

```
    <jnlp codebase="http://localhost:7070/computer/testSystem/" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
    <title>
    Agent for testSystem
    </title>
    <vendor>
    Jenkins project
    </vendor>
    <homepage href="https://jenkins-ci.org/"></homepage>
    </information>
    <security>
    <all-permissions>
    </all-permissions>
    </security>
    <resources>
    <j2se version="1.8+">
    </j2se>
    <jar href="http://localhost:7070/jnlpJars/remoting.jar">
    </jar>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main">
    <argument>
    338e93b0b127faf70a56c0edec39a70804accd7157c49e1e37e3be14aa8ea8db
    </argument>
    <argument>BAL</argument>
    <argument>-workDir</argument>
    <argument>
    C:\Jenkins
    </argument>
    <argument>
    -internalDir
</argument>
    <argument>
    remoting
    </argument>
    <argument>
    -url
    </argument>
    <argument>
    http://localhost:7070/</argument>
    </application-desc>
    </jnlp>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the downgrade of Jenkins Version to 2.303.3 seems to resolve my problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30792782)